# Hover animation transform on mouseleave

Tags: css, animation, hover, transition

I created an animation for an div, so it pulses when the mouse hovers the div. But when I leave the div with the mouse, the div snaps back into the original state. Is there possibility to transform it smoothly back to the origin?

http://jsfiddle.net/ninerian/npN89/

I tried a transition of padding and font-size, but it looks not so smooth and the origin isn't centered like with transform.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; I coudln't get it to work in jsfiddle for some reason, but that is supposed to allow the animation to complete after being stopped if it is stopped in the middle of the animation.